# List the nuget package from nexus server

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to get the nuget package list from some source
(https://nexus.sample.com) like that.When I try a below code

```
string void main(string args[])
{
  Process commandProcess = new Process();
  commandProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  commandProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Nuget\nuget.exe"; // this is the path of curl where it is installed;    
  commandProcess.StartInfo.Arguments ="list -Verbose -AllVersions -Source http://nexus.sample.com/repository/nuget-hosted/";
  commandProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  commandProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  commandProcess.Start();
  commandProcess.WaitForExit();
  string output = commandProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

the command console was not run.If I set `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput= false`.the command console was run.but I can't read the output value.Plese give any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running the executable, why don't you just use [NuGet.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) to list all packages ?

```
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("http://nexus.sample.com/repository/nuget-hosted");

foreach (IPackage p in repo.GetPackages())
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.GetFullName());
}
```

For more infos :  [Play with Packages, programmatically](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html)!

Comment: While Running above code I am facing below type of error         Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: It's because URL http://nexus.sample.com/ is invalid ! Put the right URL